# Wait for Initialize procedure(axios) before launching main application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have reactjs project which starts with `APP`

I want to do is like this below

access API -> make initialdata from API response -> show the page to user.

So I did this code but it doesn't return anything.

```
const App = () => {
    var initial_api ="/api/";
    axios.get(initial_api).then(
      function(response){
        //do some initial procedure by the response of API.
         return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<TopPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  });
}
```

I am afraid `return` is called in callback so it doesn't work.

Then, I try this too.

```
const App = async () => {
    var initial_api ="/api/";
    await axios.get(initial_api).then(
      function(response){
        //do some initial procedure by the response of API.
      }
    );
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<TopPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  });
}
```

However it shows the error like this below.

```
Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=%5Bobject%20Promise%5D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Is there any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not awaiting for the request in the index.jsx file? You could wait for axios before you render the App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. Call [`root.render(reactNode)`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#root-render) after the HTTP request success.

This is the way to launch the entire SPA after some initialization.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

const fakeAxiosGet = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: [1, 2, 3] }), 1000);
    });
};

fakeAxiosGet().then((data) => {
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App data={data} />
        </React.StrictMode>,
    );
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76736563-l8m8r6?file=/src/index.tsx)

Option 2. Launch the SPA first, fetch data(some initialization works) inside the root component - `App`, and render the routes after fetching data successfully.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const fakeAxiosGet = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: [1, 2, 3] }), 3000);
    });
};

export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState<{ data: any[]; status: string; error: string | null }>({
        data: [],
        status: 'idle',
        error: null,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState((pre) => ({ ...pre, status: 'pending' }));
        fakeAxiosGet().then((res: any) => setState((pre) => ({ ...pre, data: res.data, status: 'fulfilled' })));
    }, []);

    if (state.status === 'pending') return <p>loading...</p>;
    if (state.error) return <p>{state.error}</p>;

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            {/* routes */}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76736563-2-m6j799?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Nice and simple approach, could also have the request in a `useEffect` inside `App` (makes it easy to display the status and possible errors).

Comment: @nickzoum Yes, you can. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you ! Option 1 works perfect for me, and Option 2 is also  helpful for future case